# Почему лассо, гребневая регрессия и эластичная сеть называются именно так?

Tags: машинное-обучение, терминология

Принципы их работы описаны, но почему они названы именно так, не понятно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А погуглить, почитать? И, желательно, на английском:

[Lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) - это аббревиатура: "least absolute shrinkage and selection operator; also Lasso or LASSO"

[Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) - "Ridge regression is a special case of Tikhonov regularization in which all parameters are regularized equally." То есть это частный случай регуляризации Тихонова, при котором все параметры регуляризуются одинаково. Отсюда, видимо, и грёбёнка, символизирующая эту одинаковость.

[Elastic net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) - "the elastic net is a regularized regression method that linearly combines the L1 and L2 penalties of the lasso and ridge methods". Ну, тут я совсем гадаю, видимо, из-за линейной комбинации двух методов регуляризации этот метод назвали "эластичной сетью". Тут напрямую про это не написано, но наверняка можно ещё погуглить.

Comment: спасибо! Теперь в несколько раз понятнее стало что и как, и запомнить так легче.

Answer (score 4):

1. LASSO = Least Absolute Shrinkage and Selection Operator
2. Гребневая регрессия = тут сложно, могу лишь предположить что это потому что математики внедрившие это понятие использовали слова "хребет" и "гребень" при работе с графиками.
3. Эластичная сеть - потому что она очень удобна и объединяет лучшие качества лассо и гребневой, во всех вопросах являясь эластичной.